# How to properly configure GAE Go SDK and GoClipse on Windows from scratch?

Tags: windows, google-app-engine, sdk, installation, go

I've been a GAE Go developer for a year now, and seeing that the SDK [became available on Windows](https://developers.google.com/appengine/downloads#Google_App_Engine_SDK_for_Go), I figured I'd try it out. However, I am having problems finding any documentation on how to install it properly from scratch. I have no idea what steps to take to ensure that my projects will be running properly, so I'd like to know what is the proper way to install and configure Google App Engine Go SDK and GoClipse on Windows?

Answer (score 9):

Same here. The GAE GO SDK needs some more Windows install instructions...

As of today 2012-07-28 I just got it working on Win 7 by:

- downloading the App Engine SDK for GO here:
  developers.google.com/appengine/downloads#Google_App_Engine_SDK_for_Go
  and selected the Win 32 bit in my case
  googleappengine.googlecode.com/files/go_appengine_sdk_windows_386-1.7.0.zip
- I unzipped the GO SDK in C:\googleappenginego (make it the name you like).
- Then I added that folder path to the PATH environment variable in th System settings Advanced Settings:

My "Path" is set at:

```
C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\ThinkPad\Bluetooth Software\;C:\Program Files\ThinkPad\Bluetooth Software\syswow64;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Lenovo;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Ulead Systems\MPEG;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Live\Shared;C:\SWTOOLS\ReadyApps;%JAVA_HOME%\bin;C:\googleappenginego\
```

- I installed Python 2.7.3 from:
  www.python.org/download/
  selected this version:
  www.python.org/ftp/python/2.7.3/python-2.7.3.msi
  I installed it in the default folder C:\Python27 by launching the python-2.7.3.msi file
- I created the GO GAE project as indicated in the GAE GO Getting Started series:
  developers.google.com/appengine/docs/go/gettingstarted/helloworld
- After creating the C:\myapp\app.yaml and C:\myapp\hello\hello.go, launch the project by opening a cmd window from the Win "Start/Run..." menu.

Then type in: "dev_appserver.py c:\myapp\"
You should see something like:

```
WARNING  2012-07-28 12:32:20,154 rdbms_mysqldb.py:74] The rdbms API is not available because the MySQLdb library could not be loaded.
INFO     2012-07-28 12:32:20,650 appengine_rpc.py:160] Server: appengine.google.com
INFO     2012-07-28 12:32:20,654 appcfg.py:582] Checking for updates to the SDK.
INFO     2012-07-28 12:32:22,119 appcfg.py:600] The SDK is up to date.
WARNING  2012-07-28 12:32:22,150 dev_appserver.py:3498] Could not initialize images API; you are likely missing the Python "PIL" module. ImportError:
No module named _imaging
INFO     2012-07-28 12:32:22,163 dev_appserver_multiprocess.py:647] Running application dev~helloworld on port 8080: http://localhost:8080
INFO     2012-07-28 12:32:22,164 dev_appserver_multiprocess.py:649] Admin console is available at: http://localhost:8080/_ah/admin
INFO     2012-07-28 12:32:36,851 __init__.py:440] building _go_app
INFO     2012-07-28 12:32:37,849 __init__.py:417] running _go_app, HTTP port = 34762, API port = 42835
WARNING  2012-07-28 12:32:38,443 dev_appserver.py:2733] Failed removing c:\users\fred\appdata\local\temp\request.8mmuoy.tmp
INFO     2012-07-28 12:32:38,480 dev_appserver.py:2952] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
INFO     2012-07-28 12:32:38,588 dev_appserver.py:2952] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 200 -
INFO     2012-07-28 12:32:54,849 __init__.py:440] building _go_app
INFO     2012-07-28 12:32:55,755 __init__.py:417] running _go_app, HTTP port = 34762, API port = 42835
WARNING  2012-07-28 12:32:56,572 dev_appserver.py:2733] Failed removing c:\users\fred\appdata\local\temp\request.slayyf.tmp
INFO     2012-07-28 12:32:56,602 dev_appserver.py:2952] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
INFO     2012-07-28 12:32:56,694 dev_appserver.py:2952] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

Then go into your browser and go to "http://localhost:8080" to see your app or "http://localhost:8080/_ah/admin/" for the admin console.

Change the hello.go file, change "Hello, world" to "Hello, galaxy" for example and refresh the localhost:8080 browser window. It should show the new message without crashing or restarting the server. See right below:

**NOTE:** don't install Python 2.5.x, that was my initial mistake, despite what the GO SDK says.  It will run but it dies when I modify the hello.go source code and refresh the browser window with some like that:

```
<type 'exceptions.AttributeError'>: 'module' object has no attribute 'kill' 
      args = ("'module' object has no attribute 'kill'",) 
      message = "'module' object has no attribute 'kill'"
```

Comment: "don't install Python 2.5.x, that was my initial mistake" - you saved me.

Comment: +1 I tried to install some combinations of 4 versions of Python and 2 versions of GAE SDK and could not make it work, after I did what is in this post it started to work, I wish I looked at it sooner :) Great advice - don't download GAE msi file, use zip. Google site is quite misleading stating that go runtime uses Python runtime.

Comment: +1 for giving me an out of the box working install first time. Google SDK setup page should link to your answer :)